# How to write number with sign on the left and thousands separator point

Tags: abap

I am holding the number in character format in abap. Because I have to take the minus from right to left. So I have to put the number to character and shift or using function **'CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT'** I'm moving minus character to left.

But after assigning number to character it doesn't hold the points. I mean my number is;

- 1.432- (as integer)
- -1432 (as character)

I want;

- -1.432 (as character)

is there a shortcut for this or should I append some string operations.

**Edit:**

Here is what I'm doing now.

```
data: mustbak_t(10) TYPE c,
      mustbak like zsomething-menge.

select single menge from zsomething into mustbak where something eq something.
mustbak_t = mustbak.

CALL FUNCTION 'CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT'
  CHANGING
  VALUE         = mustbak_t.

write: mustbak_t.
```

Comment: Can we see the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a recent release, you could use [string templates](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenstring_templates.htm) - you'll have to add some black magic to use a country that confoirms to your decimal settings, though:

```
DATA: l_country TYPE t005x-land,
      l_text    TYPE c LENGTH 15,
      l_num     TYPE p LENGTH 6.

SELECT SINGLE land
  INTO l_country
  FROM t005x
  WHERE xdezp = space.

l_num = '-123456'.
l_text = |{ l_num COUNTRY = l_country }|.

WRITE: / l_text.
```

In this case, you need a country code to pass to the `COUNTRY` parameter as described in the [format options](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapcompute_string_format_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_16@16@). The values of the individual fields, namely `T005X-XDEZP` are described in detail in the [country-specific formats](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abencountry_formats.htm).

tl;dr = Find any country where they use "." as a thousands separator and "," as a decimal separator and use that country settings to format the number.

---

You could also use classic formatting templates, but they are hard to handle unless you have a fixed-length output value:

```
DATA: l_text TYPE c LENGTH 15,
      l_num  TYPE p LENGTH 6 DECIMALS 2.

l_num = '-1234.56'.
WRITE l_num TO l_text USING EDIT MASK 'RRV________.__'.
CONDENSE l_text NO-GAPS.

WRITE: / l_text.
```

Comment: could you please share some details on what that |{ }| notation does (or how it's called)? never encountered that before.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean These string templates are failry new - I've added a link to the online documentation.

Comment: Minor comment, but xdezp eq space gives comma as decimal separator?

Comment: @tomdemuyt: I've tried to explain this - it's buried quite deep inside the documentation pages.

Comment: Thanks @vwegert, second one solved my problem anyhow. For the first way, it doesnt recognize what '|{' is as I also don't.

Comment: @Mtok be careful with that second way. As vwegert said, if you've got more than 6 digits (or less than 4), your output will get messed up :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, which i finally got working:

```
DATA: characters(18) TYPE c,
      ints TYPE i VALUE -222333444.

WRITE ints TO characters. "This is it... nothing more to say.

CALL FUNCTION 'CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT'
  CHANGING
    value = characters.

WRITE characters.
```

Since integers are automatically printed with the thousands separator, you can simply output them to a char data object directly using `WRITE TO` with no aditions..... lol

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA: currency TYPE cdcurr,
      characters(18) TYPE c,
      ints TYPE i VALUE -200000.

currency = ints.
WRITE currency TO characters CURRENCY 'USD' DECIMALS 0.
CALL FUNCTION 'CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT'
  CHANGING
    value = characters.
.
WRITE: / 'example',characters.
```

This prints your integer as specified. Must be apparently converted to a currency during the process.

Comment: thanks @vlad-ardelean, but it's with comma, such as -1,432. I need with point, -1.432

Comment: should work now. I got the default decimals out of the chars.

Comment: @Mtok also, now i updated the currency to be of a more intelligible type. You could use any data element for a CURR domain though.

Comment: but now, when you got the decimals out of char, i get just 1. Because it accepts 432 is decimal because of the comma and I get just 1. :)